# How to place two webforms next to each other in Drupal 7

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I am new to Drupal. I have two webforms in a page. In Drupal on creating multiple webforms they are placed below one another. I want to place them side by side.

Answer (score 0):

There're variety way of doing it. Maybe the easy way through UI is to use panels module, and then setup a two column layout, after that you can drag each webform into one if webform has a block display.

You can achieve the same thing through hook menu and do your own theming, but that will cost a bit more time, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but for anyone else that stumbles in here, just use CSS.

```css
@media screen and (min-width: 719px) {
  form#webform-client-form-30 {
    width: 48%;
    float: left;
  }
}
```

Mobile first, so put them next to each other if the screen is > 719px. Add padding, margin, etc if desired.